# How to install wildcard SSL on second server

Tags: apache, security, ubuntu, ssl, https

I bought a wildcard SSL cert from GoDaddy and installed it on an ubuntu / apache server.

I need to install it on another server now but GoDaddy is zero help.

I can't find any good directions online either.
Anyone have a good resource for this?

I think you have to export the certs and key from your first install... and import to the second server... but I have no idea how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had been given bad information.
The answer is... as long as you are moving the wildcard cert to another server of the same type... you don't have to do anything special.

Just move the key and certs to the new server.
Edit your apache sites-available conf files.
Restart apache.

FYI all the wildcard certs needs to be on the same domain:

```
mysite.com
blog.mysite.com
support.mysite.com
```

etc.